# It's possible wait for a variable in Ruby, (without sleep)?

Tags: ruby, ssh

I’m trying to get data from an ssh server, but this action takes some time to run, so I need to wait for them, once I have them, I’ll use this data to send them through my Bot to Slack.

Here my code:

```
def sshPingRequest()
    Net::SSH.start('xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx', 'root', :port => "3132") do |ssh|
        output = ssh.exec!("ansible -m ping c3")
        result = output.split("\n").select { |line| line.include?("SUCCESS") || line.include?("FAILURE") }
        puts "############## Done #############"
        return result
    end
end

SlackRubyBotServer::Events.configure do |config|
    data = sshPingRequest() # Help
    config.on :command, '/ans-ping' do |command|
        command.logger.info 'Received a ping, responding with pong.'
        { text: data }
    end 
end
```

Basically I need to wait for the "result" variable to be ready from the first function, and after sending it in the second function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused? Why do you actively wait for the first method to set its return value? Shouldn’t the method block until it is done with processing and ready to return a result anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about promises? Could it be what you are looking for?

https://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/1.1.5/Concurrent/Promise.html

From the docs:

> Promises are similar to futures and share many of the same behaviours.
> Promises are far more robust, however. Promises can be chained in a
> tree structure where each promise may have zero or more children.
> Promises are chained using the then method. The result of a call to
> then is always another promise. Promises are resolved asynchronously
> (with respect to the main thread) but in a strict order: parents are
> guaranteed to be resolved before their children, children before their
> younger siblings. The then method takes two parameters: an optional
> block to be executed upon parent resolution and an optional callable
> to be executed upon parent failure. The result of each promise is
> passed to each of its children upon resolution. When a promise is
> rejected all its children will be summarily rejected and will receive
> the reason.

Also you can see this guide:

https://medium.com/@gauravbasti2006/lets-keep-our-promise-in-ruby-e45925182fdc

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net/SSH)

> Requests are sent from the client to the server, and are answered asynchronously. This gives great flexibility (since clients can have multiple requests pending at a time), but it also adds complexity. Net::SSH tries to manage this complexity by providing some simpler methods of synchronous communication (see Net::SSH::Connection::Session#exec!).

So,I think that you could call SlackRubyBotServer::Events.configure intro channel NET::SSH

```
def foo()
  SlackRubyBotServer::Events.configure do |config|
  data = sshPingRequest() # Help
  config.on :command, '/ans-ping' do |command|
    command.logger.info 'Received a ping, responding with pong.'
    { text: data }
  end 
end

def sshPingRequest()
  Net::SSH.start('xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx', 'root', :port => "3132") do |ssh|
    output = ssh.exec!("ansible -m ping c3")
    result = output.split("\n").select { |line| line.include?("SUCCESS") 
      || line.include?("FAILURE") }
    puts "############## Done #############"

    foo() # while the channel is open

    return result
  end
end
```